# Import android.support.v4.Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JicNB.png)

Hi there 
I face a problem with android studio, 
it could not find the " fragment" in library, 
i try to fix it from project structure and dependency then + then add "com.android.support:support-v4" but nothing changed. 
your turn experts :).

Comment: did you do gradle sync.?

Comment: It's `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. You're missing `app`.

Comment: i did, also dose not work

Comment: also i did rebuild and clean project

Answer (score 1):

go into the `build.gradle` (module app) file and you'll have something like this:

```
dependencies {

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'

}
```

Add this line to it: `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'` and than a bar in the top will appear, click rebuilt.

That's how you import libraries.